# Search for all children items in parent folder google drive api

Tags: search, google-drive-api, children

Since in V3 children was deprecated, i'm trying to get another way to search inside parent folder (using parent id) and get all children inside within subfolders too.
Didn't find a way how to do it in drive docs.
Please advice.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me:

```html
function getChildFolders(folderId){
 
  var q = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and '"+folderId+"' in parents";
  var children = Drive.Files.list({q:q});
  var res = [];
  
  for(var i=0; i<children.items.length; i++){
    res.push(children.items[i].title);
    res = res.concat(getChildFolders(children.items[i].id));
  }
  
  return res;
  
}

Logger.log(getChildFolders(rootId));
```

But getting all (grant)child folders at once does not seem possible indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Drive API doesn't have a search filter like "return all children of FOLDER_NAME".  The only available search queries are found in [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters).

But, there's a somewhat similar filter you can use, but this time, using the parent folder's ID. This applies to subfolders too.

So for example you have this URL of the parent folder which contains your files.

```
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/123456789
```

Use the search query

```
'123456789' in parents
```

and it will return all the files inside that folder.

Give the [Files.list Try-it](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) a test.

Comment: problem is that i cannot get children files. only same dir

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use this 2 functions..

```
/**
 * Export Array Files N' Folder Names from Drive Folder 
 */
function listCurFoldersEFilesName(folderId) {

   var data= [];
   var j =0 , i = 0;

   var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFolders(); //returns a FolderInterator

   while (folders.hasNext()) {
     var folder = folders.next();
     var folderName = folder.getName();
     data[j] = folderName.trim();
     j++;
   }

   var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles(); //returns a FileInterator

   while (files.hasNext()) {
     var file = files.next();
     var fileName = file.getName();
     data[j+i] = fileName.trim();
     i++;
   }
   return data; 
}

/**
 * Export Array Files N' Folder IDs from Drive Folder 
 */
function listCurFoldersEFilesIDs(folderId) {

   var data= [];
   var j =0 , i = 0;

   var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFolders(); //returns a FolderInterator

   while (folders.hasNext()) {
     var folder = folders.next();
     var infolderId = folder.getId();
     data[j] = infolderId;
     j++;
   }

   var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles(); //returns a FileInterator

   while (files.hasNext()) {
     var file = files.next();
     var infileId = file.getId();
     data[j+i] = infileId;
     i++;
   }
   return data; 
}
```